# Why are 'out' parameters in .NET a bad idea?

Tags: .net

Why are 'out' parameters in .NET a bad idea?

I was recently asked this, but I had no real answer besides it's simply unnecessarily complicating an application. What other reasons are there?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Well, they aren't a bad idea I think.  `Dictionary<K, V>` has a `TryGetValue` method which is a very good example why out parameters are sometimes a very nice thing to have.

You should not overuse this feature of course, but it's not a bad idea per definition.  Especially not in C# where you have to write down the `out` keyword in function declaration *and* call which makes it obvious what's going on.

Comment: The problem is you don't have to write the out keyword for objects and they can still be changed within the method causing side-effects. I personally much prefer the functional programming paradigm.

Comment: No, you're wrong. The object's contents may change, but the object itself cannot be **exchanged** to another object, unless you pass it with `ref` or `out`. That's the real point in those modifiers! And yes, I agree that this hits functional paradigm heavily. But still it has a merit sometimes.

Comment: Microsoft also says you should "Avoid out parameters" 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms182131(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 20):

If you care about writing reliable code by embracing immutability and removing side effects, then out parameters are an absolutely terrible idea. It forces you to create mutable variables just to deal with them. (Not that C# supports readonly method-level variables anyway (at least in the version I'm using, 3.5)).

Secondly, they reduce the compositionality of functions by forcing the developer to set up and deal with the variables which receive the out values. This is annoying ceremony. You can't just go and compose expressions using them with anything resembling ease. Therefore code calling these functions quickly turns into a big imperative mess, providing lots of places for bugs to hide.

Comment: `out` parameters can be useful in a few special situations exactly *because* they prevent function composition: For example, when a function might return a `null` value, and you want to force the caller to explicitly check for `null` before the function result is passed to the next function.

Comment: This is what Option/Maybe monads are for.

Comment: Also its a pain to reuse this damn method with 128 parameters out. There is a co-worker that LOVE doing this and I have a very hard time maintaining his code.

Comment: Nullable variables are a much better option if you have a method that may return either a value or nothing. If you want to return multiple variables, consider using tuples.

Answer (score 14):

They are a good idea. Because sometimes you just want to return multiple variables from one method, and you don't want to create a "heavy" class structure for this. The wrapping class structure can hide the way the information flows.

I use this to:

- Return key and IV data in one call
- Split a person name, into different entities (first-, middle-, lastname)
- Split the address

Comment: If you don't want a "heavy" class structure, what's wrong with using a struct in C# instead of a full-blown class?

Comment: Because it will add complexity to your code. Instead of a simple call, you have added a dependency to an extra type.

Comment: This answer incorrectly suggests that using out parameters is the only way to return multiple values from a function without defining a type beforehand.  There are bad, weakly typed ways to do this, e.g. returning a List<object> or an ArrayList.  There are also good, strongly types ways, e.g. returning KeyValuePair<T, U> for two values or an anonymous type for more than two values.  None of these approaches require defining a class or struct in advance.

Comment: "Because it will add complexity to your code".  Using out parameters instead of user defined types makes code less complex to write.  But it makes code much more complex to read.  Out parameters confuse the normal semantics of method argument passing.  Most people find functions whose arguments are inputs and whose return values are outputs easier to understand.  If you want to use out parameters at all, it would be much more straightforward to avoid return values entirely, and instead require all output as out parameters.  Then people who use your code can find the outputs in one place.

Comment: Wrong. At least in 2018. Return a tuple.

Comment: I wonder what others have to say about @Raman's comment.  Isn't is troublesome to have to look for the meaning behind Item1, Item2, etc, vs having a struct with named members?

Comment: @Dave you can still return a struct with named parameters if the complexity of the thing you are returning warrants it -- but, in most cases the use case mentioned by GvS of needing out parameters to return multiple values can be handled with a tuple and destructuring: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct -- with destructuring your values are all named, all the time.

Answer (score 8):

Out - Parameter are a bad idea in my opinion. They increase the risk of side effects and are hard to debug. The only good solution are function results and here is the problem: For function results, you have to create for every complex result a tuple or a new type. Now it should be fairly easy in c#, with anonymous types and generics.

And by the way: I hate side effects too.

Answer (score 6):

The wording of the question is [of the *"Have you stopped hitting your wife?"* variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)—it assumes that *out* parameters are necessarily a bad idea. There are cases where *out* parameters can be abused, but…

- They actually fit very well in the C# language. They are like *ref* parameters except that the method is guaranteed to assign a value to it and the caller doesn't need to initialize the variable.
- Normal return values for functions are pushed onto the stack where they are called and exited. When you supply an *out* parameter, you're giving the method a specific memory address to stick the result in. This also allows for multiple return values, though using a struct often makes more sense.
- They are wonderful for the TryParse Pattern and also provide metadata for other things like in the case of SQL-CLR where *out* parameters are mapped to *out* parameters of a stored procedure signature.

Comment: LOL .. I found this after Hanselman listed "Why are out parameters a bad idea in .NET? Are they?" as an interview question, and the first thought I had was, "When did you quit beating your wife?" Your answer shows we were thinking the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, but out parameters are unnecessary and unsafe. It creates another avenue for  side effects. If a struct or object is passed in, it's unclear which members were changed without inspecting the code. As for value vs reference, C# is not C++. The compiler should determine the optimal way to pass parameters. Finally, the TryParse    it's been superseded by nullable types.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that your answer is spot on; it's *generally* unnecessary complication and there's usually a simpler design. The majority of the methods you work with in .NET don't mutate their input parameters, so having a one-off method that utilizes the syntax is a bit confusing. The code becomes a bit less intuitive, and in the case of a poorly documented method, we have no way of knowing what the method does to the input parameter.

Additionally, method signatures with out parameters will trigger a Code Analysis/FxCop violation, if that's a metric you care about. In *most* cases, there's a better way to accomplish the intent of a method that uses an "out" parameter and the method can be refactored to return the interesting information.

Answer (score 3):

It's not always a bad idea to use out parameters. Usually for the code that tries to create an object based on some form of input it's a good idea to provide a **Try** method with out parameters and boolean return value, not to force the method consumer to wrap try catch blocks all over, not to mention the better performance.
Example:

```
bool TryGetSomeValue(out SomeValue value, [...]);
```

this is a case where out parameters are a good ideea.

Another case is where you want to avoid costly large structure passing between methods.
For example:

```
void CreateNullProjectionMatrix(out Matrix matrix);
```

this version avoids costly struct copying.

But, unless out is needed for a specific reason, it should be avoided.

Comment: Your second example could be rewritten as matrix.CreateNullProjectionMatrix (), i.e. a member function. Or use a constructor parameter to specify the initial matrix state. Or use derived types to initialise based on type (i.e. ProjectionMatrix : Matrix).

Comment: The point of the second example is that it avoids struct copying. If it were to return the Matrix as a function return value, the Matrix would have been pushed in the stack prior to function exit the poped out after function return, in my example this doesn't happen

Comment: Performance cannot be an argument. Refactoring the code so the struct is not copied upon return is something the compiler should (and can, often trivially) do. Pushing this task to the programmer is wrong and no argument for `out` at all.

Comment: Konrad, check out XNA Class library, out is used extensively for performance reasons. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195649.aspx for example. 

Feel free to browse for more.

Comment: @KonradRudolph  I definitely concur, yet I don't understand, however, how the Swift programming language encourages the use of out parameters, even when it has nullable types.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no clear answer for this,but simple use case for out parameter would be `Int.TryParse("1",out myInt)`

The [XXX.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_TryParse_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Int32__) method job is, it converts a value of some type, to another type, it returns to you a boolean flag to indicate the conversion success or failure, which is one part the other part is the converted value, which is carried by the out parameter in that method.

This TryParse method was introduced in .NET 2.0 to get over the fact that [XXX.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) will throw an exception if the conversion fails and you had to put in `try/catch` around the statement to catch it.

So basically it depends on what your method is doing, and what the method callers are expecting, if you are doing a method that returns some form of response codes, then the `out` parameters could be use to carry out method returned results.

anyway Microsoft says "*Avoid using out parameters*", in their [design guideline (MSDN page)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they are.  Misusing them is a bad idea, but that goes for any coding practice/technique.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say my reason to avoid it, would be because it is simplest to have a method process data and return one logical piece of data. If it needs to return more data it may be a candidate for further abstraction or formalization of the return value.

One exception is if the data returned is somewhat tertiary, like a nullable bool. It can be true/false or undefined. An out parameter can help solve a similar idea for other logical types.

Another one I use sometimes is when you need to get information through an interface that doesn't allow for the 'better' method. Like using .Net data access libraries and ORM for example. When you need to return the updated object graph (after an UPDATE) or new RDBMS-generated identifier (INSERT) plus how many rows were affected by the statement. SQL returns all of that in one statement, so multiple calls to a method won't work as your data layer, library, or ORM only calls one generic INSERT/UPDATE command and can't store values for later retrieval.

Ideal practices like never using dynamic parameter lists, or out parameters, aren't always practical all the time. Again, just think twice if an out parameter is the really right way to do it. If so, go for it. (But make sure to document it well!)

Answer (score 2):

Out parameters are bad. They make code harder to read and harder to maintain.

The TryParse pattern is often used as a good example for out parameters but the pattern itself is flawed by design in multiple ways.

There are 2 possible situations with parsing:

- The value MUST be parseable, if not => handle exception.
- The value MIGHT be parseable, if not assign some fallback value to it and continue.

Neither of those is facilitated by TryParse. Far more usefull would be
`int TryParse(string value, int fallback)`.

But the real problem with the `bool TryDoSomething(SomeThing something, out someResult)` pattern is that the initial boolean result is quickly converted into an integer to have a third, fourth, fifth,... result and before long code gets littered with magical return values.

A far better solution is NOT using a 'Try Do Something' with an out parameter at all (or other functions with an out parameter). Just have the code return its result and let it throw exceptions for exceptional situations.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer you gave is about the best there is. You should always design away from `out` parameters if possible, because it usually makes the code needlessly complex.

But this is true of just about any pattern. If there is no need for it, don't use it.

Comment: I think a blanket statement asserting that 'it usually makes the code needlessly complex' is a pretty gross generalization.  There are lots of contexts in which using an out parameter would simplify your design, not complicate it.  That's why it's in the language in the first place.

Comment: @Ben Collins: I know, that is why I said "usually", "if possible", etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with GateKiller.  I can't imagine out parameters being too bad if Microsoft used them as part of the base library.  But, as with all things, best in moderation.

Answer (score 1):

It's like the Tanqueray guy likes to say-  Everything in moderation.

I definitely would stress against over-use, since it would lead to "writing c in c#" much the same way one can write java in Python (where you're not embracing the patterns and idioms which make the new language special, but instead simply thinking in your old language and converting to new syntax).  Still, as always, if it helps your code be more elegant and make more sense, rock out.

Answer (score 1):

the '`out`' is great!

It makes a **clear** statement that the parameter holds a value to be returned by the method.

The compiler also forces you to **initialize** it (if we are using as a return parameter, it should be initialized).

Comment: Yes, 'out' is an improvement over nothing, but it doesn't change that 'out' parameters are abused to no end these days.

Answer (score 1):

They just ruin the semantics of a method/function a bit. A method should normally take a bunch of things, and spit out a thing. At least, that's how it is in the minds of most programmers (I would think).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a real reason although I haven't seen it used that often (other than [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) calls).

Answer (score 0):

The out keyword is necessary (see `SortedDictionart.TryGetValue`). It implies pass by reference and also tells the compiler that the following:

```
int value;
some_function (out value);
```

is OK and that `some_function` isn't using an unitialised value which would normally be an error.

Comment: If you weren't using out values, you'd never have to worry about that as it would all be on one line: int value = some_function(); Cleaner, simpler, easier than an out value.

Comment: @weberc2: My point being that you may want to have a function return two or more values, as I gave for example: SortedDictionary.TryGetValue (), and that the 'out' parameter is initialised by the function and is not to be considered an uninitialised value when it is used later on in the function. The code in my answer was just an example. You're right, `value = some_function()` would make more sense in this particular case, but that wasn't the point. The point was to show that the compiler wouldn't complain about using an unitialised value in the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I think in some scenarios they are a good idea because they allow more than 1 object to be returned from a function for example:

```
DateTime NewDate = new DateTime();
if (DateTime.TryParse(UserInput, out NewDate) == false) {
    NewDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Very useful :)

Comment: It is irrelevant to initialize the variable as it because of the out keyword always will be treated as an unassigned parameter to the method (until set).

I would also avoid using the equals false syntax and just negate the expression itself.

Comment: I could never understand rationale behind this "if (b == false)" stuff. Shouldn't you expand this into even more explicit "if ((b == false) == true)"? :)

Comment: @Constantin, what I find more gross is seeing something like this:
if (x == true) 
     return true;
else
      return false;

Comment: Python does the same thing more sanely, IMO, with its multi-params: var1, var2 = functionWith2ReturnValues(). Under this paradigm, parameters come in, output comes out. End of story. I don't know how easy this is to do without the assistance of an interpreter, but it's almost certainly cleaner and more logical.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages outside of [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) use them as do-nothing macros that simply give the programmer information about how the parameters are being used in the function.

Answer (score 0):

One point I don't see mentioned is that the out keyword also requires the caller to specify out.  This is important since it helps to make sure that the caller understands that calling this function will modify his variables.

This is one reason why I never liked using references as out parameters in C++.  The caller can easily call a method without knowing his parameter will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is "...Although return values are commonplace and heavily used, the correct application of **out** **and** ref parameters requires **intermediate design and coding skills**. Library architects who design for a general audience **should not expect users to master working** with out or ref parameters."

Please read more at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The out variable is not bad anyway, its really a cool stuff to use out if we need to return multiple (2 specifically) variables from a function. Sometimes its really tedious work to create a custom object just for the purpose of returning 2 variables, out is the ultimate solution.

Comment: c# tuples are much better for this