# Trying to parse a string in C# using the TryParse helper method

Tags: c#, string, parsing, boolean, tryparse

I'm trying to parse user entered text into a float so that I can perform some wicked awesome math on the result. The result being the numberA variable at the end there. This is how I'm parsing the string into a float:

```
numberAString = GUI.TextField(new Rect(25, 100, 100, 25), numberAString.ToString());
bool ParsableCheckA = float.TryParse(numberAString, out numberA);
```

I eventually multiply numberA by another float later. I'm handling text that won't parse with a simple error message later. Couple things that bug me:

1) Why do I need to use numberAString in the TryParse parameters instead of its value? Why can't I just drop GUI.Textfield etc. into that slot? Why do I need to break this up over two lines of code?

2) I get a warning that I never use ParsableCheckA (which is true). But without it, I can't seem to use that Tryparse helper, no? Is there a way to eliminate the need for that bool? Thanks.

Comment: For your second question you can use `float.TryParse(numberAString, out numberA);` and ignore the return value. For your first question I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: 1) no, you should not need to do that. 2) the reason you `TryParse` is so you can test for success instead of try/catch. In other words, you want to make sure it was a number and it did parse correctly.

Comment: Habib, you're right. I must have missed that I could just use the float.TryParse method. Thought I had tried it, but I guess I didn't set it up correctly. My first question, nm. I figured it out. Syntax error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

`TryParse()` Metod and its usage is rather straighforward, as shown in the following example:

```
double _dblOriginal;
_dblOriginal=3.141592;

string _str;
_str = _dblOriginal.ToString();

double _dblParsed;
bool _parseOK= TryParse(_str, out dblParsed);
```

More details in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

*Note*: make sure that in your example the string `numberAString` you pass to the `TryParse()` method contains a valid number.

Also, FYI: `TryParse()` method has some performance benefits compare to just `Parse()` method because it does not throw an exception if parsing fail (instead you just check the `bool` result value).

Hope this will help. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

(1) `numberAString` ([see GUI.TextField](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html)) *is* a string, so you can use it directly in the `TryParse()` call.
(2) `TryParse()` is designed to return a boolean value so you can check for errors and take action.  However, you aren't *required* to assign the return value. You can us it like this and simply accept the default value (`0.0`) assigned to the `out` parameter:

```
float.TryParse(numberAString, out numberA);
```

In this case you would not be able to distinguish between an invalid entry and a value that parsed correctly as zero.

Comment: Ok, I took another look at what I was trying to do and I see it all more clearly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I personally create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to make my number parsing easier. If performance is critical, then this may not be a good idea (because for valid floats, you'll be essentially converting them twice). But I don't the effect on performance is much more than negligible.

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
    //Test if the text represents a valid float.
    public static bool IsFloat(this string text)
    {
        float dummy = 0;
        return Float.TryParse(text, out dummy);
    }
    //Convert the text to a float. Will throw exception if it's not a valid float.
    public static float ToFloat(this string text)
    {
        float number = Float.Parse(text);
        return number;
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
string text = "123";
if(text.IsFloat())
{
    //text must be a valid float
    float myfloat = text.ToFloat();
}
else
{
    //text isn't a valid float
}
```

You have to remember to test if it's a float by calling the `IsFloat()` extension method, but it's much easier for me to think of it conceptually like this rather than using out variables, which [some think is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134063/why-are-out-parameters-in-net-a-bad-idea).